# Builder design pattern: Why do we need a Director?

Tags: design-patterns, builder

Recently I've come across the Builder design pattern. It seems that different authors use "Builder pattern" to refer to different flavours, so let me describe the pattern I'm asking about.

We have an algorithm for creating *products*, i.e., objects of different types.  At a sufficiently high level of abstraction the algorithm is the same for all product types, but each product type requires a different implementation of each of the algorithm's abstract steps.  For example, we might have the following cake-baking algorithm:

```
 1. Add liquids.
 2. Mix well.
 3. Add dry ingredients.
 4. Mix well.
 5. Pour batter into baking pan.
 6. Bake.
 7. Return baked cake.
```

Different cakes would require different implementations of these steps, i.e., what liquids/dry ingredients to use, what speed to mix at, how long to bake, etc.

The pattern says to do it like so.  For each product we create a *concrete builder* class with an implementation for each of the above steps. All of these classes are derived from an *abstract builder* base class, which is essentially an interface.  So, for example, we will have an abstract base class `CakeBaker` with pure virtual methods `AddLiquid()`, `MixLiquids()`, etc.  The concrete cake bakers will be concrete subclasses, e.g.,

```
class ChocolateCakeBaker : public CakeBaker {
public:
   virtual void AddLiquids()
   {
        // Add three eggs and 1 cup of cream
   }

   virtual void AddDryIngredients()
   {
       // Add 2 cups flour, 1 cup sugar, 3 tbsp cocoa powder,
       // 2 bars ground chocolate, 2 tsp baking powder
   }
      ...
      ...
};
```

The `LemonCitrusCakeBaker` would also be a subclass of `CakeBaker`, but would use different ingredients and quantities in its methods.

The different cake types will similarly be subclasses of an abstract `Cake` base class.

Finally, we have a class to implement the abstract algorithm.  This is the *director*.  In the bakery example we might call it `ExecutiveBaker`.  This class would accept (from the client) a concrete builder object and use its methods in order to create and return the desired product.

Here's my question.  Why do we need the director to be separate from the abstract builder?  Why not roll them into a single builder abstract base class, making the original abstract builder's public methods protected (and the concrete subclasses override these as before).

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The core portion of the Builder pattern concerns the Abstract Builder and its subclasses (concrete builders). According to [GoF's Design Patterns](http://amzn.com/0201633612), director simply "notifies the builder whenever a part of the product should be built", which can be perfectly done by the client.

The [StringBuilder](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.java.html) class in the Java API is an example of a builder without the respective director -- typically the client class "directs" it.

Also, in [Effective Java](http://amzn.com/0321356683) and [Creating and Destroying Java Objects](http://www.drdobbs.com/jvm/creating-and-destroying-java-objects-par/208403883?pgno=2), Joshua Bloch suggests the use of the builder pattern, and he does not include a director.

Comment: Does that mean that in an MVC application, a controller (actually a method of the controller, in my specific case) could be the "director"?

Answer (score 33):

The GoF variation of the Builder pattern does NOT have the Builder WITHOUT the Director. There's a different point to this, but I'll explain further.

The Builder pattern's point is to give you multiple ways to create the same object. Builder should only have methods which build different parts of an object, but the algorithm - the way these functions are executed - should be the concern of the Director. Without the Director every client would have the need to know EXACTLY how the building works. But with the Director all the Client needs to know is what Builder to use in a specific case.

So, what we have here are two parts:

1. The Builder, that creates parts of the object one by one. The important thing to note is that for this it keeps state of the created object.
2. The Director, that controls the way Builder`s functions are executed.

Now to the point I was referring earlier. The Builder part of the pattern is useful in other cases and has been used by different vendors WITHOUT the Director for different purposes. A concrete example of such use would be the [Doctrine Query Builder](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html).

The disadvantage of such approach is when the Builder starts to build an object it becomes stateful and if the Client doesn't reset the Builder after the object was created - another Client or the same Client that has been used more than once could get the parts of the object that was created earlier. For this reason, Doctrine uses the Factory pattern to create every instance of the Builder.

I hope this helps those googling.

Comment: You can just apply CQS and make the builder read-only. Thus you don't have to wonder if the state was modified.

Answer (score 16):

If you separate into Director and Builder you have documented the different responsibility of assembling a product from a set of parts (director) and the responsibility of creating the part (builder).

- In the builder you can change how a part is build. In your case whether a `AddLiquid()` should add cream or milk.
- In the director you can change how to assemble the parts. In your case a by using `AddChocolate()` instead of `AddFruits()` you get a different cake.

If you want this extra flexibility, I would rename to (since using baker in the builder suggests, it was the builders job of assembling the parts)

```
class LightBakingSteps : public BakingSteps {
public:
    virtual void AddLiquids()
    {
        // Add milk instead of cream
    }

    virtual void AddDryIngredients()
    {
        // Add light sugar
    }

    ...
};

class ChoclateCakeBaker : public CakeBaker {
public:
     Cake Bake(BakingSteps& steps)
     {
         steps.AddLiquieds();
         steps.AddChocolate();      // chocolate instead of fruits
         return builder.getCake();
     }
}
```

Comment: But what is the advantage of this separation?  If I want different assembly protocols, I'll need to have different directors, each tailored to a specific (abstract) builder.  These directors don't share any common functionality that can be abstracted, except, perhaps MakeSomething(), which isn't useful.  You can always break any task into ever smaller subtasks and reponsibilities, and you can always add another level of "manager" or "director" to any pattern.  I'm thinking that the authors of this pattern likely were thinking along the lines you have outlined, but I can't see the value in it.

Comment: @Ari and you can't see value in it because value of programming patterns is inherently chained with domain your program is about. why there should be particular baker for every cake there is? take away domain - it's all just a noise, random characters on screen. that is what I meant in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Builder knows how to do specific steps.
Director knows how to assemble the whole thing using builder steps.

They work together.

The only fragility that I can see with this pattern is that client is able to call Builder methods directly without Director - that may bring some issues and incoherence (for example not calling Init method that is part of whole algorithm)

Answer (score 3):

Let's say that you want to make a cake without the dry ingredients. What you are going to do is just adding a new method into the Director or making another Director. This will protect you from inheritance complexity and also will make your code more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with you. I think that the other approach is that the CakeBaker should have a GetCake() method which returns a cake(Cake class) and MakeCake() method where the algorithm will run. That's fine  but on other hand there is a responsible separation there. Consider abstract builder and specific bulders as builders of a cake parts only and Director as manager or designer whose responsibility is to assemble and produce a cake.

Comment: Separation of responsibility left me unconvinced.  In some cases it might make sense to separate; in others not.  I don't see this as part of the pattern but rather as an orthogonal decision.

Comment: Learning DPs I try to get their principles not copy them literally. Moreover in practice I often make a combination of them. So it's not necessary to code the same number of classes or interfaces as in doc but rather make your code more flexible and modifiable.

Answer (score 0):

Downside of patterns is that they pollute our understanding of business domain with technical terms and blurs our focus.

As I see it - there is too much coupling in between cake and knowledge of how to make it. Those can be decoupled by introducing an idea of cake having a recipe in our code (more like borrowing from real world, designing our model by business domain). Recipe would have ingredients and baking steps (just a step name, not actual implementation because recipes don't bake cakes) on how to make cake what recipe describes. Our baker would have a method BakeCake(recipe), and bunch of smaller methods according to baking steps like mix, add ingredient, etc.

Be aware that if you would need to model chef in general, not just cake baker, you would also need to decouple knowledge of making bakes from baker itself too. It could be done by introducing idea of chef having a skill.

Comment: This looks more like an alternative to the pattern than an explanation of it.  Did I misunderstand?

Comment: @Ari indeed it is. technically - I'm not answering question. just wanted to remind that patterns themselves aren't that important. it's like with spoken language - you must know at least basics of it, but in the end - it is what you want to say that matters.